# Mismatching .NET versions on compile even though I have all the .NET versions installed

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, using

I am writing my custom Grasshopper components in Visual Studio 2013 RC using C#. However, when on compile, I get the following error:

```
The primary reference "Grasshopper" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v2.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Grasshopper" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".   MassAddition2
```

I suspected that it's because my .NET was out of date, but when I use the .NET 4.5 updater, it tells me I have 4.5 or higher installer. Locating my registry version, here is what I see

[image]

Because I cannot reference these assemblies/libraries, my code is unable to run or compile. I get the blue underline my `using`:

[image]

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: It looks like the `Grasshopper` assembly depends on `System.ServiceModel` which is part of .Net 3, yet your project is targeting .Net 2, so `System.ServiceModel` is not available. You need to change the target version of your project to 3 or higher.

Comment: **retarget your application to a framework version which contains System.ServiceModel** says it all, IMO. As @Lee says, change your target to .Net 3 or higher.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers guys - I'm pretty new to C# development and the VS IDE in general. How do I retarget my application to this framework version that will contain System.ServiceModel?

EDIT: Just Googled it.